# Extract elements in format from list

Tags: python, list, csv

Extracting from the csv below

```
1,'Chaks, Raj','$300,000', False
2,'Chen, Joe','$250,000', False
3,'Kumar, Harry','$240,000', True
```

I am iterating over the List, first list is below

`M = ['1', "'Chaks", " Raj'", "'$300", "000'", ' False']`

COde is below

```
for i in M:
   empid = i[0]
   print (empid)
   name = row[1].replace(',','').replace('$','') if row[1] else '-'
   print (name)
   salary = row[3].replace(',','').replace('$','') if row[3] else 0
   print ('salary',salary)
```

Expected out

```
1
Chaks Raj
300000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you adding a more explicit description of what are you trying to achieve here, or what is your specific question.

In any case, interpreting your question a bit, I understand that you want to avoid parsing the values with `','` inside the CSV.

I would recommend you to use the `csv` module for doing this, so you end up having something like this:

```
import csv

lines = '''1,'Chaks, Raj','$300,000', False
        2,'Chen, Joe','$250,000', False
        3,'Kumar, Harry','$240,000', True'''.splitlines()

for l in csv.reader(lines, delimiter=',', quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
    print('\n'.join(l))
```

Notice how I pass the `quotechar="'"` key/value parameter, so the reader uses that kind of quotes for separating values inside the CSV.

For more documentation about this module see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.